# Android Options Menu for login

Tags: android

how to change android option menu in session management.
session.isLoggedIn();
menu items:-
Login
Logout
my code is

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    if(session.isLoggedIn()){
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_logout).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_register).setVisible(false);
    }else{
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_logout).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_register).setVisible(true);
    }

    return true;

}
```